# Material design select with search

Tags: jquery, select, material-design, materialize

I'm looking some kind of select with search input. I built my page with materializecss, but this library does'nt support this type of select. Here is best example what i need - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select#select-header. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add search functionality using [Select2](https://select2.org/) as described in [this](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3096#issuecomment-216980931) GitHub issue. All you need to do is:

1. Add Select2 style sheets and javascript files (including jQuery) to your page.
2. Add extra CSS to make Select2 look more like materializecss.
3. Run javascript code to initialize Select2 on `select` elements.

```js
$('select').select2({width: "100%"});
```

```css
.select2 .selection .select2-selection--single, .select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 2.05rem;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple, .select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.select2-results__option {
    color: #26a69a;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
    background-color: #eee !important;
    color: #26a69a !important;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
    background-color: #e1e1e1 !important;
}

.select2-dropdown {
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[role=group] .select2-results__group {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fff;
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field:focus {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
    min-height: 2.05rem !important;
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=time],
input[type=date],
input[type=datetime-local],
input[type=tel],
input[type=number],
input[type=search],
textarea.materialize-textarea {
  &.valid + label::after,
  &.invalid + label::after,
  &:focus.valid + label::after,
  &:focus.invalid + label::after {
    white-space: pre;
  }
  &.empty {
    &:not(:focus).valid + label::after,
    &:not(:focus).invalid + label::after {
      top: 2.8rem;

    } 
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: this one truly is life saver for me

Comment: How do i handle on change? of the value?

Comment: Experiencing so many issues with select2 in bootstrap modal. Not working for me